# can two tabs to same SPA and web server share a common websocket?

Tags: linux, web, websocket

Assume a web application (in my case, [bismon](https://github.com/bstarynk/bismon/); a GPLv3+ program which is work in progress, so alpha state, and not even released; I am incrementally writing  [bismon-chariot-doc.pdf](http://starynkevitch.net/Basile/bismon-chariot-doc.pdf) which is a *draft* report describing it; skip the first few bureaucratic pages.) which is (or should be) a single web page application. That web application uses a Web socket for asynchronous messages sent from web application (the web "server") to all tabs of the same page. That websocket is not used for communication from web browser tabs to web server. There is one `bismon` multi-threaded server process (running on Linux), and it is a specialized web server (the same one for both tabs in the question).

Assume the user is using a recent web browser on Linux (e.g. Firefox 60.5 at least). He/She is doing "open in new tab" on some hyperlink (which points to the same web application server process and the *same* page). My guess is that an *existing* WebSocket might be shared between the two tabs (if that is impossible, why?). Then what happens when the Web server is sending a JSON message on that WebSocket? Do the two tabs get it "in parallel"? Why and how? If that is impossible, why and how?

The closest MCVE I have is my [onionwebsocket.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/misc-basile/blob/master/onionwebsocket.c) example on github (an adaptation of [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)'s `examples/websockets/websockets.c` code). Code given below, of course a recent libonion (an HTTP server library) is required. Each tab is handled by its own thread. It does not share websockets between tabs, but I can't understand how even I would try to.

I would like websockets (with data asynchronously flowing from server to browser) to implicitly have some "locking" (or serialization) of each WebSocket message. I am not even sure if it is possible or makes sense. How do browsers do in practice? AFAIK, each tab of my Firefox has its own *process* (but actually not, it looks a tab corresponds to a browser pthread), so how would these tabs share some "state" like a WebSocket? How two tabs in the same browser share data and websockets? How do they "synchronize"? What is happening inside `bismon` when some thread is writing to the *same* WebSocket, with the browser having *two* tabs handling incoming messages from it?

For completeness, here is the `onionwebsocket.c`  code I've got (but I don't understand all the subtleties of WebSockets - I find their specification too breve.).

```
/**
  onionwebsocket.c: my adaptation of Libonion's
  examples/websockets/websockets.c to learn more about websockets.

  Libonion is on  https://github.com/davidmoreno/onion

  Copyright (C) 2010-2019 David Moreno Montero, Basile Starynkevitch
  and others

  This [library] example is free software; you can redistribute it
  and/or modify it under the terms of, at your choice:

  a. the Apache License Version 2.0.

  b. the GNU General Public License as published by the
  Free Software Foundation; either version 2.0 of the License,
  or (at your option) any later version.

  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
  GNU General Public License for more details.

  You should have received a copy of both licenses, if not see
  <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/> and
  <http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0>.
*/

#include <features.h>
#include <onion/log.h>
#include <onion/onion.h>
#include <onion/websocket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdatomic.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef HAVE_GNUTLS
// on Debian, install libcurl4-gnutls-dev & gnutls-dev pacakges before
// building libonion
#error without HAVE_GNUTLS but onion needs it
#endif

onion_connection_status websocket_example_cont (void *data,
                        onion_websocket * ws,
                        ssize_t data_ready_len);

onion_connection_status
websocket_example (void *data, onion_request * req, onion_response * res)
{
  onion_websocket *ws = onion_websocket_new (req, res);
  if (!ws)
    {
      time_t nowtim = time (NULL);
      char timbuf[80];
      static atomic_int acnt;
      atomic_fetch_add (&acnt, 1);
      memset (timbuf, 0, sizeof (timbuf));
      strftime (timbuf, sizeof (timbuf), "%c", localtime (&nowtim));
      onion_response_write0 (res,
                 "<html><body><h1 id='h1id'>Easy echo</h1>\n");
      onion_response_printf (res,
                 "<p>Generated <small><tt>%s</tt></small>, count %d, pid %d</p>\n",
                 timbuf, acnt, (int) getpid ());
      onion_response_write0 (res,
                 "<pre id=\"chat\"></pre>"
                 " <script>\ninit = function(){\n"
                 "msg=document.getElementById('msg');\n"
                 "msg.focus();\n\n"
                 "ws=new WebSocket('ws://'+window.location.host);\n"
                 "ws.onmessage=function(ev){\n document.getElementById('chat').textContent+=ev.data+'\\n';\n"
                 "};}\n"
                 "window.addEventListener('load', init, false);\n</script>\n"
                 "<input type=\"text\" id=\"msg\" onchange=\"javascript:ws.send(msg.value); msg.select(); msg.focus();\"/><br/>\n"
                 "<button onclick='ws.close(1000);'>Close connection</button>\n"
                 "<p>To <a href='#h1id'>top</a>.\n"
                 "Try to <i>open in new tab</i> that link</p>\n"
                 "</body></html>");
      printf ("websocket created acnt=%d timbuf=%s\n", acnt, timbuf);
      fflush (NULL);
      return OCS_PROCESSED;
    }

  onion_websocket_printf (ws,
              "Hello from server. Write something to echo it. ws@%p",
              ws);
  onion_websocket_set_callback (ws, websocket_example_cont);

  return OCS_WEBSOCKET;
}

onion_connection_status
websocket_example_cont (void *data, onion_websocket * ws,
            ssize_t data_ready_len)
{
  char tmp[256];
  if (data_ready_len > sizeof (tmp))
    data_ready_len = sizeof (tmp) - 1;

  int len = onion_websocket_read (ws, tmp, data_ready_len);
  if (len <= 0)
    {
      ONION_ERROR ("Error reading data: %d: %s (%d)", errno, strerror (errno),
           data_ready_len);
      return OCS_NEED_MORE_DATA;
    }
  tmp[len] = 0;
  onion_websocket_printf (ws, "Echo: %s (ws@%p)", tmp, ws);

  ONION_INFO ("Read from websocket ws@%p: %d: %s", ws, len, tmp);

  return OCS_NEED_MORE_DATA;
}

int
main ()
{
  onion *o = onion_new (O_THREADED);
  onion_set_port (o, "8087");
  onion_set_hostname (o, "localhost");

  onion_url *urls = onion_root_url (o);

  onion_url_add (urls, "", websocket_example);

  onion_listen (o);

  onion_free (o);
  return 0;
}


/****************
 **                           for Emacs...
 ** Local Variables: ;;
 ** compile-command: "gcc -o onionwebsocket -Wall -rdynamic -I/usr/local/include/ -O -g -DHAVE_GNUTLS onionwebsocket.c -L /usr/local/lib $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gnutls) -lonion" ;;
 ** End: ;;
 ****************/
```

---

To run that example, use `http://localhost:8087/` in your Linux browser after starting the  `./onionwebsocket` program whose compilation command is near the end of the code.

Ideally, I would like all the tabs to share the same websocket connection and the webserver to send a "broadcasted" message to all tabs of the same browser (hopefully that the actual "broadcast" or "multicast" happens on the browser side). But I believe it is not possible (but I don't understand why).

I'm reading [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2352693) that "the Web Content process *is* the tab". I don't understand what that means. On my Debian/Instable I don't have it, but I do observe with `ps auxw | grep firefox` *several* `firefox-esr` processes with  for example arguments similar to `-contentproc -childID 1 -isForBrowser` which seems to be *undocumented* options of the Firefox browser.

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1252151/107016) could be related, but I don't understand why and how.

In other words, what is supposed to happen if the *same* WebSocket is used by two tabs and is receiving (browser-side) the same JSON message? Or is that impossible? Why?

PS. I do admit I am too lame to dive into the 50MLOC of `firefox`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking about the way the browser avoids race conditions? (it uses an event loop and a single thread per tab, so there's no race conditions in the javascript data, only in the event loop scheduling, which is protected)... or are you asking about `libonion` "locking" (which I'm not familiar with, but [facil.io locks each connection separately](http://facil.io/0.7.x/fio#fio_defer_io_task))...? As for sharing WebSocket connections across tabs, [it isn't possible on all browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=shared%20web%20workers).

Comment: Two tabs of Firefox might (if I understand correctly, but I could be wrong) run in two different processes. Then what happens when both tabs recieve, using the *same* WebSocket, the same message (e.g. a JSON one) from the web server?

Comment: unless both tabs use the same shared web worker, than they will receive two different messages each from a separate WebSocket connection (to the same server). If they do share the connection using a shared web work, they will receive two different event notifications from each separate connection to the shared web worker. In any case, each tab will have a separate event loop. JavaScript always appears single threaded to the browser‘ script.

Comment: @Myst: with a code example, that could become an answer

Comment: I’m at the airport. When I get to sit with my laptop I’d be happy to write an answer :)